# Where do I register my JS so that it is added by grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, bower, yeoman

I used a yeoman generator (html5 site).

I have an existing project that I want to translate into the grunt/bower workflow.

I have a .js file that does what I want, from the old project.
Copying it into the development folder of the new bower/grunt based project does not result in it being concatenated to the concated to the final, single, mainsite.js.

So I checked the gruntfile.js and added it here:

```
concat : {
        options: {
            banner: '<%= banner %>',
            stripBanners: false
        },
        main : {
            src : [
                'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                'bower_components/jQueryui/ui/jquery-ui.js',
                'bower_components/jqueryui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js ',
                'bower_components/RWD-FitText.js/jquery.fittext.js',
                'bower_components/BrowserDetection.js/BrowserDetection.js',
                'bower_components/respond/dest/respond.src.js',
                'main-2k15-dribble/JavaScript/Main.js',
                'main-2k15-dribble/JavaScript/mainsite.js',
this added--->      'main-2k15-dribble/JavaScript/jribble.js'
            ],
            dest : 'main-2k15-dribble-pub/js/mainsite.js'
        }
    },
```

**I specifically want to know what I need to do to add my existing javascript to a project that is managed by grunt and bower ?**

*And generally I have never seen a clear description of what folder was means what and what the workflow is fro adding to a scaffolded project. yet I feel there must be some wiki or something teaching this ! i don't believe miliions of devs discover this by trail and error...*

Comment: Silly question but have you run the grunt task ?

Comment: The = which ? Grunt concat is run as part of grunt serve. I re-run grunt serve if I change the config.

Comment: Ok, sounds like it is running the concat then. Maybe check that your file is passing the 'jslint' test. http://www.jslint.com/.

I can't tell as we don't have the whole grunt file but maybe if there is some bad syntax it won't concat it.

Comment: I have the complete file here:

pastebin.com/zejAdgur

Comment: can you overwrite 'main-2k15-dribble-pub/js/mainsite.js'? Maybe it's locked by something.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot guess if you did this or not but you need to load the [`grunt-contrib-concat`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) npm and then register a task to do that, so your Gruntfile.js should look like as:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Project Configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
            options: {
                banner: '<%= banner %>',
                stripBanners: false
            },
            main: {
                src: [
                    'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                    'bower_components/jQueryui/ui/jquery-ui.js',
                    'bower_components/jqueryui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js ',
                    'bower_components/RWD-FitText.js/jquery.fittext.js',
                    'bower_components/BrowserDetection.js/BrowserDetection.js',
                    'bower_components/respond/dest/respond.src.js',
                    'main-2k15-dribble/JavaScript/Main.js',
                    'main-2k15-dribble/JavaScript/mainsite.js',
                    'main-2k15-dribble/JavaScript/jribble.js'],
                dest: 'main-2k15-dribble-pub/js/mainsite.js'
            }
        },
    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.registerTask('concat', ['concat']);
};
```

and then run it as:

```
grunt concat
```

Comment: I ran it separately to no avail. Here is the full gruntfile:

http://pastebin.com/zejAdgur

Comment: Addiung your modifications after the semicolon behing the large enclosing curly bracket resulted in a frezze :)

Both grunt serve and grunt concat freeze.

Comment: you haven't this `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');` I edited mine, there was one of your comment in a bad syntax

Comment: As I said, adding  `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');` results in a freeze/infinite loop. Maybe I added it at the wrong place ?

And is your suggestion not redundant with `grunt.registerTask('serve', [
        'clean:css',
        'less',
        'clean:js',
        'concat',
        'clean:site',
        'assemble',
        'replace:dev',
        'copy:dev',
        'connect:livereload',
        'notify:dev',
        'watch'
    ]);`